# CPU does not support Virtualization technology which is a requirement for HAXM

Tags: intel, haxm

Does anyone know a way to bypass this problem? Perhaps through a virtual machine as VMware ?

Comment: A virtual machine will also require a VT enabled processor to provide that instruction set.  You must buy a processor with the technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to buy a processor that supports it.

http://ark.intel.com/compare/75267 (Note this is just a random Xeon I picked, you will need to search for the cpu in the computer and look on Intel's ark site)

Look for Intel vPro Technology |    Yes

If your processor DOES have it marked as Yes, it is probably disabled in the BIOS and will need to be enabled.

Comment: hove can i run whitout haxm ?